# getting validate method for newly created model with foreign key to pass

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I'm trying to allow a user to create 2 models in one form. Post has a one to one relationship with Story.

My code looks something like this :

```
public function actionCreate()
{
  post = new post();
  story = new story();

  if (isset($_POST['post']))
  {
    $post->attributes = $_POST['post'];
    $story->attributes = $_POST['story'];

    // force the views to show errors for both $post and $story
    $post->validate();
    // this one will always fail because the required foreign key field is not set until the post is saved.
    $story->validate();

    if ($post->save())
    {
      $story->post_id = $post->id;
      $story->save();
    } 
  }
}
```

I need to call validate so that the view shows errors on all fields, however since the model is just being created, post doesn't have an id yet so I can't assign it to story.  This means validate for story will always fail.

Is there a way I can validate the model when it's still new without throwing away the required rule for the foreign key.

Comment: set `$story->post_id` to `default->NULL` in Db.

Comment: I don't think this will work, I believe the field will be null when it's created.  It won't validate unless it's a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with a "scenario" in which indicate when to use it and what fields does .. for example ..

```
<?php
class User extends Model
{
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $password;

    public function rules(){
        return [
            [['name','email','password'],'required'],
            ['email','email'],
            [['name', 'email', 'password'], 'required', 'on' => 'register'],
            ];
    }
    public function scenarios()
    {
        $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
        $scenarios['login'] = ['name','password'];//Scenario Values Only Accepted
        return $scenarios;
    }
}
?>

<?php
...
class UserController extends Controller
{
    ..
    // APPLY SCENARIOS
    // scenario is set as a property
    ............
    public function  actionLogin(){
        $model = new User;
        $model->scenario = 'login';
        .............
    }
    // scenario is set through configuration
    public function  actionRegister(){
        $model = new User(['scenario' => 'register']);
        ..............
    }
}
?>
```

In this sample you ca use two scenario 'login' validate two field 'register' validate three..

[see this doc for moore sample](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/yii2-0-scenarios/) and [thisi from Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html)

Comment: Thanks, this looks exactly like what I wanted.